# Converting double to string and back to double again rendering zeros

Tags: java, string, hadoop, mapreduce

I have this reducer that receives an iterable of custom objects that I process

```
ArrayList<String> rValues = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> sValues = new ArrayList<String>();

for (RelationTuple rt : values) {
    if (rt.getRelationName().equals("R")) {
        rValues.add(rt.getRelationName() + "--" + rt.getLocation() + "--" + rt.getHalf() + "--" + rt.getTuple() + "--" + String.valueOf(rt.getJoinAttribute()) + "--" + String.valueOf(rt.getDistance()) + "--" + String.valueOf(rt.getOutKey()));
    }
    else {
        sValues.add(rt.getRelationName() + "--" + rt.getLocation() + "--" + rt.getHalf() + "--" + rt.getTuple() + "--" + String.valueOf(rt.getJoinAttribute()) + "--" + String.valueOf(rt.getDistance()) + "--" + String.valueOf(rt.getOutKey()));
    }
}


for (int i=0; i < rValues.size(); i++) {
    String[] record1Parts = rValues.get(i).split("--");
    for (int j=0; j < sValues.size(); j++) {
        String[] record2Parts = sValues.get(j).split("--");
        if (!record1Parts[0].equals(record2Parts[0]) && (Double.parseDouble(record1Parts[6]) == Double.parseDouble(record2Parts[6]))){
            if (record1Parts[1].equals("home") && record2Parts[1].equals("home")) {
                context.write(NullWritable.get(), 
                        new Text(record1Parts[0] + "," + record1Parts[4] + "," + record1Parts[6] + "," + record2Parts[0] + "," + record2Parts[4] + "," + record2Parts[6]));
            }
```

The first element of the arrays record1Parts[0] and record2Parts[0] are strings throughout and go to the output just fine. Elements that are integers or doubles, that I converted to Strings, such as `rt.getJoinAttribute()` end up going to the output as zeros. What am I doing wrong with my string and double conversions that loses the number values and produces zeroes instead? I have tried not converting with `String.valueOf(...)`, but that yields the same result.

What is coming into the reducer are objects that have values for a join attribute, like 1200, values for a relation name, like R and S, values for a join key, which is an index values from 0 to 250. So I might expect output records like R, 1200, 10, S, 1220, 10. But I'm receiving output records like R, 0.0, 0, S, 0.0, 0.

Comment: I think if you showed us some sample input along with both expected and observed output, that might help to clear up this question.

Comment: Good idea, @TimBiegeleisen . I've edited my question to give you more data context.

Comment: I'm not a Map-Reduce expert, but could you trying printing the array `record1Parts` to the console?  We need to see with what you are starting before you try to split.

Comment: OK, @TimBiegeleisen, give me a sec. It can take a while to run a job in MapReduce.

Comment: The values that I used `String.valueOf(...)` on are zero and they shouldn't be. Is there anything about `String.valueOf(...)` that would take a number and make it zero?

Comment: Assuming you are passing in a `double` to `String.valueOf()`, it implies that the value of that `double` is zero.  Can you check your math to make sure that it isn't off?

Comment: The problem turned out to be something totally unrelated to what I thought it was. Kudos to you, though, @TimBiegeleisen, because your debugging advice is what led me down the correct path. So I thank you.